# Palindrome programming challenge with 2 error s

Tags: c++

## cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Pstring : public string
{
public:
    Pstring(string revWrd);
    bool isPalindrome(string ip);
};

bool isPalindrome(string revWrd)
{
    int test;
    int left = 0;
    int right = revWrd.size()-1;
    int length = left;

    while (test != length)
    {
        test++;

        if ((revWrd[left] != revWrd[right]))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
        left++;
        --right;
    }
}

int main()
{
    string word;
    bool palindrome;
    Pstring palindromeTested(word);

    cout << "Enter a word or sentence to have it\n";
    cout << "reversed and tested if it is a palindrome: ";
    getline(cin, word);
    palindrome = palindromeTested.isPalindrome(word);
    if(palindrome==true)
        cout<<"This is a palindrome"<<endl;
    else
        cout <<"That was not a palindrome";
    return 0;
}
```

i get 2 error codes which are 1 "undefined reference to `Pstring::Pstring(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >)'|"
and 
2 "undefined reference to `Pstring::isPalindrome(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >)'|

Comment: It is because the member functions in the class `Pstring` are not defined.

Answer (score 2):

The error is because the member functions in the class `Pstring` are not defined.

The class doesn't seem used effectively, so you should remove that.

Also there are some other errors:

- The variable `test` is used without being initialzed.
- `return true;` is in wrong place, making strings like `abcda` be judged as palindrome.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool isPalindrome(string revWrd)
{
    int test = 0; // initialize test
    int left = 0;
    int right = revWrd.size()-1;
    int length = left;

    while (test != length)
    {
        test++;

        if ((revWrd[left] != revWrd[right]))
            return false;
        // else
            // don't return here to check all parts of the string
            
        left++;
        --right;
    }
    return true; // return at end of funciton
}

int main()
{
    string word;
    bool palindrome;

    cout << "Enter a word or sentence to have it\n";
    cout << "reversed and tested if it is a palindrome: ";
    getline(cin, word);
    palindrome = isPalindrome(word);
    if(palindrome==true)
        cout<<"This is a palindrome"<<endl;
    else
        cout <<"That was not a palindrome";
    return 0;
}
```